# Angular ssr 17 with cloudflare, not found

Tags: server-side-rendering, angular17, angular-ssr

I have a problem with angular ssr 17 with cloudflare, the application does not work but when I disable the temporary cache in cloudflare it starts working normally, do you know if there is any type of additional configuration from the cloudflare side for ssr of angular 17? thank you

Disabling the temporary cache works but is not a permanent solution